# AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'apply'

Tags: python, opencv

**cv2 Problem.. I was watching not that old of a tutorial about object tracking and stumbled in this error**

```
AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'apply'
```

This is the code around the issue.

```
object_detector = cv2.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2

while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    mask = object_detector.apply(frame)

    cv2.imshow("Frame", frame)
    cv2.imshow("Mask", mask)
```

In The tutorial the guy did the exact same thing!!

Comment: link to the resp. tutorial, please (it should be corrected !)

Comment: https://pysource.com/2021/01/28/object-tracking-with-opencv-and-python/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you did not create the object_detector properly, it has to be:

```
object_detector = cv2.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2() # BRACES !!!
```

you only made a copy of the create() function, not invoke it)

(also, rather use [opencv's tutorials](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d1/dc5/tutorial_background_subtraction.html) for this !!)

Comment: Oh my god thank you I was staring at the code for 10 minutes haha!!